# Form not going to the #

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I have this code

```
echo '<form action="?id='.$topic_id.'&part=9&num='.$_GET['num'].'#commenting " method="POST" style="border: none; margin: 0;">';
echo '<textarea style="display: none; margin: 0;" name="old_comment">' . $row['comment'] . '</textarea>';
echo '<textarea style="width: 90%;" name="new_comment">' . $row['comment'] . '</textarea>';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Save Edit &raquo;" class="button">';
echo '</form>';
```

The form seems to ignore the #. I dug into the displayed code in chrome. It shows...

```
<form action="?id=28&part=1" method="POST" class="comment">
<textarea name='comment'></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Post Comment &raquo;" class="button">
</form>
```

#commenting just disappeared.....

Does # have some other meaning or am I doing it wrong?

EDIT:

This code loads the page and runs some code to add a comment. During that few seconds before I redirect to show the comment I would like to have the user brought down to the section where I put  so they can see the (loading gif) One moment please.. .

Would javascript be handy here?

Comment: # in a url is typically handled purely within the browser and never sent to the web server

Comment: Does that mean I can't do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, but you can't do it that way

Comment: @hallaji What are you talking about?  How is that any different for an `action`?

Comment: Don't put pseudo-tags like `[solved]` in the title of your question, and don't edit the solution into the body of your question. If you have a solution, post it as an answer below, and mark it accepted to mark this question as "solved".

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want using a `hidden` field like this :

```
echo '<input name='params' type="hidden" value="?id='.$topic_id.'&part=9&num='.$_GET['num'].'#commenting />';
```

Get the value using `$_POST['params']` and do what you want with it's value.